# Embedding Sitemap Meta Tag on Free Wordpress Blog

Tags: wordpress, meta-tags, sitemap

I have a free wordpress blogging account and I have a domain from GoDaddy which is forwarding to my wordpress blog. I want to use Google's sitemap which requires me to add the meta tag in my wordpress page.

In Google Webmaster tools or Yahoo's, if I use mysite.wordpress.com and get the meta tag in the blog, it works, but if I use my domain name like mysite.com, then it doesn't get verified. How come?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you're only forwarding the domain. It's not actually the domain of your blog, just a simple link.
If you want it to really work you should register your domain as a paid domain in wordpress (it costs like 10$ a year), and then it will work. That's what I did, and I'm pretty happy with the results.

Comment: But I bought the domain from GoDaddy. What do you mean by "It's not actually the domain of your blog"? Thank you.

Comment: I did the same (bought my domain off a different vendor and set it up for my blog on wordpress). Go to your dashboard, settings, domains. Try adding the domain there.

I actually suggest to add it through wordpress and pay the extra 10$, it's worth it. You also get a 2 days trial, so if you don't like it - there's no charge for disabling it again.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools in your WordPress.com account dashboard (http://*yourblog*.wordpress.com/wp-admin/tools.php).

Follow the instructions in the "Webmaster Tools Verification" section.

Comment: Can we see a link to your site? I'm guessing your GoDaddy domain just frames or redirects to the WordPress.com site.